# Will an iOS app with radio buttons be rejected from the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, app-store, custom-controls

If i were to write a custom renderer for a radio button control, for iOS, could it be rejected from the App Store since radio buttons aren't native controls?

An example radio button control for iOS / Android / WindowsPhone (written in Xamarin) can be viewed [here](http://mobisoftinfotech.com/resources/blog/iphone/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-radio-buttons/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple will not reject your app if create radio button.
Kindly refer:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Concepts/RadioButtons.html

Answer (score 3):

For sure APPLE will not remove the App with radio button so you can continue creating a radio button with custom renderer.
Because I already did that.

Comment: This is the reason i asked so please who might have already deployed an app with radio buttons might assist. Thanks. Would you mind telling me what the app's name is so i can download it and check it out?